# What is Parallelizing Table Creation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have seen a concept called Parallelizing Table Creation in oracle and I'm not getting whats the objective of that, is it to copy a existing table to a new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Syntax is to this process is**

To copy with all the data,

> select * into New_Table from
>   Oragnial_table

Only to copy the definition,

> select * into New_Table from
>   Oragnial_table where 1=2

Comment: What has that got to do with your original question?

Answer (score 6):

It's far more than just table creation...

[Quote](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1009052):

> If you parallelize the creation of a table, that table then has a parallel declaration (the PARALLEL clause) associated with it. Any subsequent DML or queries on the table, for which parallelization is possible, will attempt to use parallel execution.

### How Parallel Execution Works

[Quote](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_parallel_processing.html#How%20Parallel%20Execution%20Works):

> Oracle divides the task of executing a SQL statement into multiple smaller units, each of which is executed by a separate process. When parallel execution is used, the user's shadow process takes on the role of the parallel coordinator. The parallel coordinator is also referred to as parallel execution coordinator or query coordinator.